# Wordpress display specific widget of sidebar

Tags: wordpress, widget

For example; I have 10 Text widgets, but I want to display only 1 widget. Is it possible to display widget by it's name?

If I use `<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>` it will display all the widgets which are in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can display  a specific widget by passing name (also an optional parameters) check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget#Recent_Posts_widget),

```
the_widget('WP_Widget_Text', $instance, $args);
```

Comment: My code `<?php the_widget('WP_Widget_Text', 'text'); ?>` and nothing is displayied

Comment: Now display title, but not display message in textarea

Comment: `<?php var_dump(the_widget('WP_Widget_Text', 'title=123')); ?>` I get null

Comment: It should not...you must be doing something wrong over here. Can we have link to check please ?

Comment: http://testams.serveriai.lt.lazdynas.serveriai.lt/wp/

Comment: You are just passing title in parameter , try to pass `'title=123&text=something'` as mention in my answer.

Comment: But text sometimes will be changing, how  widget will work then

Comment: For dynamic try like this `the_widget('WP_Widget_Text', $instance, $args); `

Comment: Maybe I not correct register sidebar ? `<?php if ( function_exists('register_sidebars') ) { register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar'));?>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Display Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/) plugin.